# ¿Cómo elegir qué campo guarda el navegador al registrarse en un formulario para después autorrellenar?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

tengo un formulario (HTML, PHP y JQuery) de registro de usuarios con los campos email, nombre, apellidos y contraseña. El problema que tengo es que cuando se registran, los navegadores le preguntan si quieren guardar los credenciales, pero en vez de guardar el email y la contraseña, se les guarda el Nombre, con lo que después no pueden loguearse correctamente.

¿Hay alguna forma de elegir qué campo es el que guardará el navegador para decirle que sea el Email el que se guarde de forma predeterminada?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Pon el formulario HTML que tienes para que podamos reproducir tu error e indicarte cómo se podría corregir. Lée [ask], [tour] y sobretodo [example], gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, hay una forma de especificar qué campo debería guardar el navegador cuando se registra un usuario en tu formulario. Se trata de la etiqueta HTML , que puedes usar para definir los campos de tu formulario.

Para especificar qué campo debería guardar el navegador, debes incluir un atributo autocomplete en la etiqueta  correspondiente. Por ejemplo, si quieres que el navegador guarde el campo de email de forma predeterminada, tu código debería verse así:

De esta forma, cuando el usuario se registre en tu formulario, el navegador le preguntará si quiere guardar sus credenciales, y se guardará el campo de email de forma predeterminada.

Además de email, hay varios valores posibles para el atributo autocomplete, que puedes usar para indicar qué tipo de información se está guardando. Por ejemplo, si quieres que el navegador guarde el nombre y los apellidos de un usuario, tu código debería verse así:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" autocomplete="nombre" />
<input type="text" name="apellido" autocomplete="apellido" />
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.